# How can I output both the key and value of my state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I want to be able to output both the key and the value of the key of items in my state. I tried using `{[this.state[field]]}` but that didn't work either.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/164470/

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        type: 'valueOfType',
        subType: 'valueOfSubType',
        anotherThing: 'valueOfOther'
    }
  }

  renderItem = (field) => {
     return <div>{['nameOfKey']}: {field}</div>
  }

  render() {
    const { type, subType, anotherThing } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <p><strong>Actual output:</strong></p>
        {this.renderItem(type)}
        {this.renderItem(subType)}
        {this.renderItem(anotherThing)}

        <hr/>
        <p><strong>Desired output:</strong></p>
        <div>type: valueOfType</div>
        <div>subType: valueOfSubType</div>
        <div>anotherThing: valueOfOther</div>
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Pass the key as a string. Then do `this.state[field]` in `renderItem` to get the value associated with that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Li357 suggested you can pass the key as a string and use it like `this.state[field]` in your method. Alternatively, you can use `Object.entries` and `map` to render all the fields.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      type: 'valueOfType',
      subType: 'valueOfSubType',
      anotherThing: 'valueOfOther'
    }
  }

  renderItem = (field) => {
    return <div>{field}: {this.state[field]}</div>
  }

  renderAll = () => Object.entries( this.state ).map( ([key,value]) =>
    <p>{key}:{value}</p>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p><strong>Actual output:</strong></p>
        {this.renderItem("type")}
        {this.renderItem("subType")}
        {this.renderItem("anotherThing")}

        <hr />
        {this.renderAll()}

        <hr />
        <p><strong>Desired output:</strong></p>
        <div>type: valueOfType</div>
        <div>subType: valueOfSubType</div>
        <div>anotherThing: valueOfOther</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```